# What is the difference between .create() and .createCB() in Sails.js (Waterline ORM)?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

In [the Sails documentation on create](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create), the documentation talks about the function named ".create()" and use the following example with "createCB()":

```
// create a new record with name 'Walter Jr'

User.create({name:'Walter Jr'}).exec(function createCB(err, created){
console.log('Created user with name ' + created.name);
});

// Created user with name Walter Jr
// Don't forget to handle your errors and abide by the rules you defined in your model
```

What is the use of createCB and what does CB stands for ?

(Edited)

Comment: Man that CB means callback!!! it is given a name to the callback function!if you dont give that it will automatically take default!!

Comment: Oooh okay. I was confused when writing this question and reading it again, it does not make any sense. Still, createCB isn't documented anywhere. Thank you.